# I cannot stop my Google contact addresses from displaying in Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-contacts

On my phone (Note 8, Android 7.1.1), when I go into Maps and Your Places, I see hundreds (around 400) of addresses from my contact list under the Labeled tab.  Everything I've read says that if you don't want these address to display, you should go into Settings | Personal Content | Google Contacts and move the slider to the off position.  I did that (Google Contacts is now grayed out), but all of the contacts are still showing.  Hiding them one at a time would be a nightmare.

I've tried forcing the Maps app to stop hoping that would force the app to refresh the address list, but that didn't work either.  I have even tried clearing the cache and saved data for the Maps app but these Contact addresses are still showing up.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The setting you are talking about will only remove contacts from showing up in the actual map.

To remove contacts from showing in *my places* tab, do the following:

settings  → Google  → [general]  →
Personal info & privacy  → Activity controls  → Web & App Activity  → Turn "Web & App Activity" off

Comment: Thank you for that information.  If I turn off Web & App Activity, what other important features may I lose?  I like the overall functionality of Maps I just don't want to see hundreds of addresses under Your Places,  95% or better of which I will never need to access in Maps.  I guess one person's "feature" is another's PITA.

Comment: See the following link for more info: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068

Answer (score 1):

Tip: To hide all of your Google Contacts' addresses on the map, open the Google Maps app Google Maps and then tap your profile picture or initial Account Circle and then Settings and then Personal content and then next to 'Google Contacts', turn the switch off. The switch will turn grey when it's off.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3131570?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid